# Java not running in latest Firefox

Tags: firefox, java, icedtea

Java is not working or showing up in Firefox 71, though I have Icedtea installed:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin
icedtea-plugin is already the newest version (1.6.2-3ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I know Firefox and all the other browsers made a point in recent versions to disable all plugins (or only that DRM plugin and Flash if absolutely necessary?) but I don't even see the plugin in addons/plugins page. Is there a way I can re enable it?

Comment: There used to be a way to add a flag on your `about:config` page to allow other plugins besides Adobe flash but it seems that adding this on the newest versions of firefox does nothing. However, using Waterfox, which is a fork of Firefox, allows the use of NPAPI plugins and it is currently maintained. There is also a ppa for waterfox but I don't use it. To update, I just click on "help" on the top window menu and then click "about waterfox" to check for updates just like you would for a manually downloaded version of firefox on Debian or Windows.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that this is referring to waterfox "classic". I guess there is also a waterfox "current" available but I have never used it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Why do Java, Silverlight, Adobe Acrobat and other plugins no longer work?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/npapi-plugins):

> Beginning in Firefox version 52 released March 7, 2017, installed NPAPI plugins are no longer supported in Firefox, except for Adobe Flash.

However, you can install a fork of the older version of firefox that will still has support for NPAPI plugins.

One fork that is popular is [Waterfox Classic](https://www.waterfox.net/releases/) which is widely used and still updated and supported (not Waterfox Current).

Download the latest version of "Waterfox Classic" (*not the Waterfox Current version*) and extract the file. Then, go into the "waterfox-classic" directory and double-click to run the file named "waterfox".

Alternatively, if you want to do everything in the terminal, you can run the following commands instead:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget "$(curl -s https://www.waterfox.net/download/ | sed 's/https/\n\n&/g' | grep waterfox-classic | sed 's/bz2.*$/bz2/g')"
tar xvf waterfox*bz2
```

Then, to run waterfox, execute the following command:

```
~/Downloads/waterfox-classic/waterfox
```

To make it easy to run, you can set the command to a keyboard shortcut in your settings or you could try pinning it to your dock by right clicking on the icon after you get it running but sometimes that doesn't work.

---

The update feature of Waterfox Classic is broken and updates must be manually downloaded so I wrote the following script to automatically download and install the latest update. However, **do not run the script in your Downloads directory** or it will get confused.

```
#!/bin/bash
mv $HOME/Downloads/waterfox-classic $HOME/Downloads/$(curl -s https://www.waterfox.net/download/ | sed 's/https/\n\n&/g' | grep waterfox-classic | sed 's/bz2.*$/bz2/g' | sed 's/^.*water/water/g;s/\.en.*$//g')
wget "$(curl -s https://www.waterfox.net/download/ | sed 's/https/\n\n&/g' | grep waterfox-classic | sed 's/bz2.*$/bz2/g')"
tar xvf waterfox-classic*2
mv waterfox-classic*2 $HOME/Downloads/
mv waterfox-classic $HOME/Downloads/
```

This will make a backup of the old version in your Downloads directory (named with the current version number).